# Google plus java starter command-line

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I have downloaded the Google plus java starter project from [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/) 
I set up maven, created my client_id and client_secret and my api_key and put these keys into the config.properties.

Now i started to run the project.
the

```
setupTransport()
```

Method seems to work.

But if the

```
getProfile()
```

Method is called an Exception is thrown.

This is the output:

```
Attempting to open a web browser to start the OAuth2 flow
Once you authorize please enter the code here: [entered my Code here]

============== Get my Google+ profile ==============

Okt 16, 2012 1:25:10 PM Sample getProfile
Schwerwiegend: {
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "usageLimits",
"reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
"extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAsString(HttpResponse.java:464)
at Sample.main(Sample.java:45)
```

---

EDIT:

i dont know what happened, but now it works.
I only copy pasted the IDs again, refreshed my project and let eclipse build it again...

Comment: Sometimes the copy/paste of Client IDs messes up.  But I am glad to hear that it works for you.  I tested that starter on a fresh machine last week and had no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the v5 .zip package from the downloads page?
If so, could you try to [checkout the code](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-java-starter/source/checkout) for the latest version and use that instead?